# Deploy Spring boot jar file on IIS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, iis, iis-7

I need to deploy my spring boot jar file on IIS. is it possible? how? I am familiar with [tomcatiis.riaforge.org](http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org/) but for some reason, I want to use embedded tomcat and this connector won't work with it.

Comment: What force you to deploy a java based project on iis?

Comment: @STaefi I am developing a web service for a company that all of their systems are based on .NET Framework and deployed on IIS. They ask me to deploy my java based project on IIS too for the sake of integrity and ease of deploying.

Comment: Then tell them at least a java servlet container (tomcat or ...) is needed for deploying any spring boot application. IIS doesn't support the classes needed by spring boot to create the needed container for your spring boot application.

Comment: Referring to the embedded jetty of spring boot, you need to run that spring boot application as a standalone application, not by deploying it on any server. If your server machine has jre installed on it, you can create a batch file to run your spring boot application on it using the main method of the class annotated by @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Deploying spring boot application on IIS is similar to deploying a .Net MVC on tomcat on linux. How a tomcat installed on linux can run a .Net MVC project without knowing anything about .Net framework?

Comment: @STaefi Thanks for your answers. So having a jar file with embedded tomcat or jetty and run it using java commands is the best way to go?

Comment: I can tell it may be the simplest way to go but I think you may be confused by the meaning of embedded tomcat or jetty. When you are developing with java servlet technologies, by default for running it on the real usage you should deploy it on servlet container because in your codes (direct or indirect) you are using the basic codes which implemented the concepts of Servlet. Servlet containers are noting but some servers such as tomcat or any other java servers (most of them are more than just servlet container). By the word container I mean the runtime environment which let you run your codes

Comment: If you insist on not having a web server on your server machines, you should run your codes using a main class in your application annotated as `@SpringBootApplication` but instead you should setup the missing environment jar files in the class-path of running that main class. As far as I can tell it is more inconvenience to setup that environment manually and that's why servlet containers like tomcat exists. Tomcat is so lightweight and if you worry about the load or memory of something like tomcat you should not.

Comment: IIS is the best, i deploy everything on that... and i like to know how to do it with springboot too...

IIS is not just a service provider for .net application, it's one of the best manager, let us control SSL, Binding, lot of stuff in single management center... and that's why we may want to deply our website on IIS instead of TOMCAT or stand alone (BTW it seem that spring boot inject embeded tomcat, which last time i wasn't able to host my project on tomcat, but i did standalone. but i remember before spring boot, in old spring we did it in tomcat...